# Initialize VHDL array elements

Tags: vhdl, vivado

Have almost no experience with VHDL and Vivado so trying to learn even the simplest of things.
I am making a VHDL array like the below:

```
type reg is array (0 to 15) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
signal reg_file : reg;
```

Within my VHDL code I have an reset that does the following. (not the entire body, just the reset part.

```
begin    
    process(Clock,Reset)
    begin
        if (Reset = '1') then -- Reset register values to default values
            reg_file(0) <= x"0000";
            -- reg_file(1) <= x"0001";
            reg_file(2) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(3) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(4) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(5) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(6) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(7) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(8) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(9) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(10) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(11) <= x"0000";
            -- reg_file(12) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(13) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(14) <= x"0000";
            reg_file(15) <= x"0000";
```

I have commented out reg_file(12) because I want to initialize it to a certain value. I also want to initialize reg_file(1) to one (and then the remaining array elements to zero). The above code works when there is a reset signal but I am unsure of how to init only certain array elements.

Is there a way to initialize certain VHDL array elements? All examples I have seen are of initializing the entire array.

Comment: reg_file <= (12 => certainvalue, others => "0000");  Aggregate value elements can be associated by named association, here the index. This method is only valid for values of an array composite type (as here). Consider providing an [mcve] so a solution can be demonstrated to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can groups assignments like this:

```vhdl
if (reset = '1') then
  reg_file(0) <= (others => '0');
  -- skip 1
  reg_file(11 downto 2) <= (others => (others => '0'));
  -- skip 12
  reg_file(15 downto 13) <= (others => (others => '0'));
end if;
```

A better solution would be to describe the properties of your register file in an array or array of a record:

```vhdl
constant resetable : boolean_vector := (
  0 =>        true,
  1 =>        false,
  2 to 11 =>  true,
  12 =>       false,
  12 to 15 => true
);
```

```vhdl
if (reset = '1') then
  for i in reg_file'range loop
    if (resetable(i) = true) then
      reg_file <= (others => '0');
    end if;
  end loop;
end if;
```

So why did I mention an array of records for the configuration? Maybe you want to define the reset value, which might not be always "000...000". Moreover you might want to define if a register should do auto clear on read or write if a register can generate an interrupt, etc...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Paebbels says, you must realize that values are determined by the final assignment in a sequence

```vhdl
a <= '0';
a <= '1'; -- no error to overwrite, a = '1';
```

Thus you could just set everything to `'0'` and then change the indices you want differntly

```vhdl
if (Reset = '1') then
  reg_file <= (others => (others => '0'));
  reg_file(1) <= x"DEAD";
  reg_file(12) <= x"BEEF";
else ...
```